# HTTP subscription model using python

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to access a server using a subscription model, i.e. I send a POST to subscribe, receive an acknowledgement, then I receive unsolicited incoming packets (which I must acknowledge).  To make them stop I should unsubscribe.
I want to implement my client in python - I first tried with Requests, but I cannot find a way to receive the unsolicited updates.  I then went to urllib2 and tried repeated response.read() calls after a successful subscription but I get no further data.  Can someone suggest a good approach please?

Comment: What protocol do you plan to use ?

Comment: If you want to receive HTTP requests, you'll have to run an HTTP server which can receive incoming connections.

Comment: Not strictly HTTP, but did you look into WebSockets? There's a python module of course: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html